# PyMC and MCMC: How to ignore a sample?

Tags: pymc

I have an if-condition in my model. Only when this if-statement is true, I want to return the result to the sampler.

For the else-statement, is there a return value I can use to tell the sampler to ignore the draw?

Answer (score 0):

Any time you return a likelihood of -inf you will be guaranteed that a draw is rejected, and the current draw will be retained, according to the Metropolis algorithm. So, you can return `-np.inf` when your condition is not satisfied, if you like.